# How do I play a sequence of animations (from different controllers) after a widget loads?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

A screen in my app has three buttons. When the screen loads I am trying to have the following sequence happen:

- widget loads
- button 1 animation
- pause
- button 2 animation
- pause
- button 3 animation

Each button is it's own widget with it's own AnimationController and a playAnimation() function. I have tried multiple ways of doing this and can not get this to work.

If I use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback():

```
    @override
    void initState() {
        ...
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            button1.playAnimation();
            sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
            button2.playAnimation();
            sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
            button3.playAnimation();
        });
        ...
    }
```

I get:

- blank screen
- 2 second pause
- widget loads
- all animations play at the same time

If I put print statements in I can see the app cycling through the the button presses on the blank screen.

If I use FutureBuilder():

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ...
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
                button1.playAnimation();
                sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                button2.playAnimation();
                sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                button3.playAnimation();
            }),
            ...
        );
    }
```

I get:

- widget loads
- all animations play at the same time

It seems the FutureBuilder method is 'closer' to a solution. However, I can't find anything on how to get multiple animation controllers to run in a sequence like this. From what I can tell, staggered animations only work on a single controller/widget.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

U can do that with one Controller by dividing its duration interval to many animation sequences.

> [Check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8jD8ixkXXk)
> [My Code sample](https://github.com/jbjason/animations_anatomy/blob/main/lib/screens/challenges_/batman_chlng/batman_signin_screen.dart)